# Discretization in Drake

Tags: drake, discretization

So I am doing a zero order hold integration technique for discretization. From the [text](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/underactuated.html), there is an explicit expression describing the discrete dynamics.

How do I look at the explicit form of my linearized system from Drake? I want to know the A, B, and C matrices to use in explicitly  writing out my discrete time dynamics.

Also, Is there a technique in Drake which does discretization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [`Linearize(system, context)`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__primitive__systems.html#ga80a6af98e4258a474416aae6ab3abdd8) in drake, you get back a `LinearSystem` object.  You can then call [`A()`, 'B()`, etc](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_affine_system.html#ace583a472a3bdc1b67f05d6a6571a903) on that object to get the matrices.

If you linearize a continuous-time system, you will get a continuous-time linear system out.  If you linearize a dicrete-time system, you'll get the discrete-time system out.  I think your proposal is to linearize the continuous-time system then do the zero-order hold in [section 10.2.4](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/trajopt.html#section2)?  That sounds very reasonable.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!